# Building an index table from a MySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

Using MySQL and PHP; I'm trying to build an index that contains the averages from table_1 grouped by:

type, name, hour, day, month, year

So I need to know which combination's of values are in table_1 so I know what to put in my AVG() queries.

What I want is to figure out all the different combination's that can be made when comparing the following rows in the table:

```
type
name
hour
day
month
year
```

Here's an example of table_1:

```
ID|type|name|location|amount|year|month|day_num|day|hour|minute|second

1|car|ben|1|1.00|2010|10|01|Friday|03|05|45
1|car|bob|1|3.00|2010|10|01|Friday|04|05|45
2|cow|bob|2|2.00|2009|07|12|Sunday|09|10|12
2|cow|ben|2|4.00|2009|07|12|Sunday|10|10|12
```

So what I would end up with is:

```
type|name|year|month|day|hour    

car|ben|2010|10|01|Friday|03
car|bob|2010|10|01|Friday|04
cow|bob|2009|07|12|Sunday|09
cow|ben|2009|07|12|Sunday|10
```

How would I format a query to do that?

Comment: Just to be certain: Do you want to find all combinations that *exist* right now, or the combinations that are *possible* with the existing values?

Comment: All the combinations that exist right now.

Comment: Why in the world don't you use a DATETIME? All information would still be available (even the weekday).

Comment: @halfdan because I want to find averages based off of individual hours, days, months... DATETIME puts all the date and time info in one column; making it more complicated to find the averages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just want the combinations that exist, you can simply run this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT type, name, hour, day, month, year FROM table
```

This goes through all of the rows, and for each combination that exists in the table, that combination will be output once in the result set.